# MongoDB Atlas with "Full Document" enabled returns only the changed item, not the full document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to use Triggers with MongoDB Atlas to notify on changes to a document in my collection. I want to receive the full document that had any data in it change, and use that full document upon receipt of the change notification. In the triggers configuration, there is a slider to enable/disable "Full Document" which has the following description:

> By turning on Full Document, you will receive the document created or
> modified in your change event. For Delete operations, the full
> document will not exist.

However, with or without that slider enabled, I get the same results.

Here is my change listener code:

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true  })
await client.connect().then(db => {
    const collection = client.db("database_name").collection("collection_name")
    const changeStream = collection.watch()
    changeStream.on("change", async data => {
        console.log("Detected database change on", Date())
        console.log(data) // only returns changed data
    })
})
```

Here is the example output, which as stated doesn't include the full document despite the trigger configuration:

```
{
  _id: {
    _data: '82606C926E000000012B022C0100296E5A10049008F3458DF14719A9225DF7AB403CEC46645F69640064606C76124670930F9A1F657C0004'
  },
  operationType: 'update',
  clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1617728110 },
  ns: { db: 'database_name', coll: 'collection_name' },
  documentKey: { _id: 606c76124670930f9a1f657c },
  updateDescription: {
    updatedFields: {
      my_data: 'my changed data',
      created: 1617728109618
    },
    removedFields: []
  }
}
```

The full document should look like this:

```
{
  _id: 606c76124670930f9a1f657c,
  myKey: 'something that never changed',
  my_data: 'my changed data',
  created: 1617728109618,
  expires: 'some time in seconds that never changed',
  other_info: 'something that never changed'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated... e.g. do I need to add a function in the trigger configuration to return the full document? If so, what would such a function look like?

Comment: What is the connection between triggers and change streams?

Answer (score 1):

I typically don't like answering my own questions, but I figured I'll post the answer here anyway in the event someone else needs it.

After a bit more digging, it looks like `collection.watch()` can accept options. With Full Document enabled in Atlas, my code needed this:

```
const changeStream = collection.watch([], { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' })
```

Now the full document is returned as expected. The documentation I found comes from [here](https://www.plusnconsulting.com/post/MongoDB-Change-Streams/), and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/).